# What are appropriate measures to only allow logins from a given trusted OpenID-Provider?

Tags: openid, single-sign-on

I have a bunch of applications, where users need to log in. Not everyone can be a user, each user has to be approved of by an admin. The authentication should be a SSO solution, where user accounts are created and managed in a central application.

My idea is to use OpenID. The central application acts as OpenID-Provider for all the other applications. But of course, **only** users from that single OpenID-Provider should be able to log into the system, other OpenID-Providers must be ignored. So the question is:

**How can a relying party make sure that a user actually has an account on a given OpenID-Provider, assuming that OpenID-Provider is trustworthy to  the application?**

Some assumptions that can be made:

- The identifiers of the users are all https-URLs pointing to the OpenID-Provider, which answers discovery-requests for unknown accounts negatively.
- All connections to the applications and the OpenID-Provider are HTTPS-secured (HTTP will be redirected).

My idea is to simply check the identifier when a login-attempt occurs, and make sure it is an URL to that single trusted OpenID-Provider. Because OpenID includes the discovery step, which is *always* executed, the relying party will send an request to the trusted OpenID-Server, which will either answer with discovery information if the user exists, or an error, which lets discovery and therefore authentication fail.

Because everything goes through HTTPS, the relying party can also be sure that the request to the identity-URL will actually go to the correct server.

Does my approach work? Or does someone know a better way to restrict the accepted Providers?

Comment: Maybe look into OpenID Connect - which is basically OpenID + OAUTH2.